# Random wordpress utf8 character encoding issue - Opera only

Tags: wordpress, utf-8, character-encoding, opera

I have a weird issue with character encoding on some pages that are not actually part of wordpress, but bootstrap it and get their data from the WP database. I get the odd characters like "Äƒ".

Wordpress v3.2, content is new, not migrated from older WP version.
Database encoding is UTF8, collation is utf8_general_ci.
My config file has define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8'); and define('DB_COLLATE', 'utf8_general_ci');
My php files are encoded as UTF8 without BOM.

Even weirder is that it sometimes displays as good on this page: http://ro.c4studio.ro/, but after I reload the page (it may take more than one reload) it goes bad. It's almost never right on this page: http://ro.c4studio.ro/contact/ (sometimes displays ok).

Also it only happens on Opera (latest version)? Tried deleting cache as well...

I don't get it? why does it sometimes work and sometimes not?

Fun, isn't it :-)

Answer (score 3):

Opera clearly makes a wrong guess about the encoding of some file that makes up the site, it guesses (alternatively is configured to use or falls back on) iso-8859-1 when the content is actually UTF-8.

First of all make sure you have "View > Encoding" set to automatic detection.

To really get to the bottom of the problem you need to figure out what URL Opera makes the wrong guess for. How exactly is the data delivered - directly inside the markup or in some external feed (like a JSONP SCRIPT or RSS feed)? (I don't actually see any problems on the site, so I can't tell from here). Then make sure this URL is sent with the **correct HTTP Content-type header**, for example for a HTML page it should be

```
    Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
```

Answer (score 2):

Examining the page source, it appears that you are using the newer HTML5 way of specifying the charset:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
```

I would try using the current way of doing this to see if that fixes the issue:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Comment: That should make no difference, both work fine in Opera (and have for a long time — it was deliberate the HTML5 way works in all major browsers going back over a decade, with the exception of IE/Mac).